# Problema mysql a la hora de hacer select a una tabla o vista

Tags: mysql

Acabo de migrar una base de datos de 5.0.95 a 8.0.16 para una migración de maquina `Racktables`, tengo un problema con una vista, a la hora de la creación, la crea correctamente:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`rackuser`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `Row` AS select `O`.`id` AS `id`,`O`.`name` AS `name`,`L`.`id` AS `location_id`,`L`.`name` AS `location_name` 
from ((`Object` `O` left join `EntityLink` `EL` on(((`O`.`id` = `EL`.`child_entity_id`) and (`EL`.`parent_entity_type` = 'location') and (`EL`.`child_entity_type` = 'row')))) left join `Object` `L` on(((`EL`.`parent_entity_id` = `L`.`id`) and (`L`.`objtype_id` = 1562)))) 
where (`O`.`objtype_id` = 1561)
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Pero cuando quiero hacer `select` sobre la vista me indica lo siguiente:

```
select * from Row;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Row' at line 1

En la maquina anterior funciona perfectamente la vista. pero en la nueva maquina no me deja ver la creación de esta y como he indicado hacer el `select`, me pasa lo mismo si la creo como tabla.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: el caso es que si hago select * from `Row` entrecomillado si me hace bien la consulta, pero necesito que la vista funciones sin el entrecomillado.

Comment: Row es una palabra reservada por lo que no puedes usarla sin comillas. De hecho no se debería poder usar sin ellas pero mysql debe permitirlo. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Buenas, no hay alguna manera de deshabilitarlo¿? el programa que estoy usando tiene la tabla principal Row y sin ella no carga nada, un salufo y gracias.